# Looking for a way to stop memory leak in this basic program

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks, tkinter

I'm new to Python. This program creates a label inside a Tk() window. The word "hi" is written into the label indefinitely. How can I delete the old hi's while still writing new ones indefinitely? Is that even how I stop the memory leak? Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

def box(a):
    z=Label(root,text='%s'%(a))
    z.place(width=50,height=20)

def start(root):
    a="hi"
    box(a)
    root.after(100, start, root)

root = Tk()
start(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just replace the text instead of creating the `Label` object every time.

```
from tkinter import *

def box(a):
    z['text'] = a

def start(root):
    box('hi')
    root.after(100, start, root)

root = Tk()
z = Label(root, text='')
z.place(width=50, height=20)
start(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

```
from tkinter import *


def start(root, z):
    a = 'hi'
    z['text'] = a
    root.after(100, start, root, z)


root = Tk()
z = Label(root, text='')
z.place(width=50, height=20)

start(root, z)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This definitely fixed the memory leakage, but now the pythonw CPU usage is spiking up to 50%!! With my code it would start at about 2% and slowly increase as more memory was leaked

Comment: @JohnW4, Replace `1` with `100`. I changed the value from 100 to 1 to test it. Now I updated the answer to change `1` to `100`.